# Umbraco NodeByAlias?

Tags: user-controls, umbraco

I'm developing a custom datatype with the usercontrolwrapper in umbraco. I have some dataeditorsettings which I need the value of.

```
dynamic landkaart = new DynamicMedia(umbraco.library.GetPreValues(1100));
dynamic pointer = new DynamicMedia(umbraco.library.GetPreValues(1100));
```

As you can see I'm working with the `GetPrevalue()` method so I can access these values. The only problem now is that I do not want to hardcode those id's. I guess I need some method like `NodeById()`, except for the fact that I want it by property alias. Does anyone know a method like that, or knows a method which I can use to get the id of the property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is the solution i came up with:

```
Document d = new Document(@Model.Id);
var pt = d.getProperty(propAlias).PropertyType;
var preVals = PreValues.GetPreValues(pt.DataTypeDefinition.Id);
```

Comment: Thnx! Keep in mind that in this example preVals is an array. So to acces these values one could use: 

    ((PreValue)preVals[index]).Value;

Answer (score 2):

If you use uComponents you can get an Id from its name - but I'm not sure if that will work with PreValues (are you using Umbraco Contour?)

```
var prevalueId = uComponents.Core.uQuery.GetNodesByName("MyPrevalueName").First().Id;
```

To remove the magic number hardcoding you could move the '1100' into the web.config and give it a name of your own:

```
<add key="PrevalueNodeName" value="MyPrevalueName"/>

var prevalueId = uComponents.Core.uQuery.GetNodesByName(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PrevalueNodeName"].ToString()).First().Id;
dynamic landkaart = new DynamicMedia(umbraco.library.GetPreValues(prevalueId));
```

or if the prevalues don't like being accessed by name:

```
<add key="PrevalueNodeName" value="1100"/>

var prevalueId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PrevalueNodeName"].ToString())
dynamic landkaart = new DynamicMedia(umbraco.library.GetPreValues(prevalueId));
```

Comment: Thnx for the answer amelvin! But i already found another solution. I'll post it later this day. Ill still mark this as answer ;).